# How to count runs of identical elements in a list?

Tags: python-3.x

I am working through Automate The Boring Stuff. I have been stuck for hours on a challenge. I am *almost* there. The challenge is to create a coin toss simulator, and count runs of like results. Specifically, I am looking to capture any run of like elements occurring 6 or more times in a row.

I've written the code below. It is right in 99% of circumstances except I happened to catch an error - it misses a run of 6 if that run is also the last 6 elements in the list (it may do this if it is the first 6, but I haven't been able to simulate it, and if I knew why it would do that, I could probably solve the problem). Any input would be gratefully received.

```
import random

# Generate a list simulating 100 coin tosses, where 'H' = Heads, 'T' = Tails

for experiment_number in range(10000):
    results = []
    for i in range(100):
        if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
            results.append('H')
        else:
            results.append('T')


# Code that checks if there is a streak of 6 heads or tails in a row.


number_of_streaks = 0


last_item = None
current_streak = 0
for item in results:
    if item == last_item:
        current_streak += 1
        if current_streak >= 6:
            number_of_streaks += 1
    else:
        current_streak = 0
    last_item = item

print(results)
print(number_of_streaks)
```

As above, I've struggled, and come up with what's ultimately quite a straightforward solution. It's just wrong in a fraction of cases and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
streaks = [[streak,i] for i, streak in enumerate(results) if len(set(results[i:i+6]))==1 and len(results[i:i+6])==6]
```

With this list comprehension you will get a list of tuple with: `['coin_results', index]` values, indicating the index and type of results which occurred exactly 6 times in a row in your experiments.

To handle the case where there are more than 6 occurrences of the same 'coin_results' e.g.:

```
streaks = [['H', 36], ['H', 37]]
```

I would pass streaks to this function

```
def real_occurrences(streaks):
      real_streaks = streaks
      for i,streak in enumerate(streaks[:-1]):
              if streaks[i][1] == streaks[i+1][1]-1:
                     real_streaks.pop(i+1)
      return len(real_streaks)
```

getting `[['H', 36]]`